# MS-Word template, change default new name to something else than "Document1"?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, templates

For work I have a couple of MS-Word templates (Office 2010) and they're named:

```
Study address labels 7 x 3.6.dotx
Study invitation.dotx
Study informed consent.dotx
etc.
```

When a user double clicks the template to create a new document, the default name is always `Document1`. I've right clicked and opened the template, opened `File -> Info -> Advanced properties` and set the `Title` to for example "Study address labels" but that doesn't seem to change anything, when I create a new document the default name is still Document1.

So my question is; is it possible to change the default new document name to something other than "Document1", for example "Study invitation1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. A new MS-Word document is always automatically named "Document**n**", where **n** is the document's serial number in the current session, even if you create the document using a template with a custom document title. The title is only applied (instead of the default "Doc**n**") when you try to save "Document**n**", which is likely to be the first thing you do when creating a new document, anyway.

Comment: Doh! You're right, I was just looking at the "Document1" at the top of the window, but when you save it then the filename in the savefile dialog is the title of the template.

Comment: Lesson learned: Things like underscores and hyphens will result in truncation at those characters. Ex. SE-SU-1234 just shows SE, SE_SU-1234 just shows SE, SESU1234 shows SESU1234